# What does (string * string) list -> (string -> string) mean?

Tags: ocaml

This might be a super dumb question, but I don't get it.
What does
`(string * string) list -> (string -> string)` mean?
Especially the last part `(string -> string)`. How can you achieve that?

I thought it'd be an inner function but it isn't I guess.

Answer (score 5):

`string -> string` indicates a function which takes a `string` and returns a `string`. Similarly, `int -> int` would indicate a function which takes an `int` and turns an `int`.

`string * string` indicates a tuple of two strings. `(string * string) list` indicates a list of those tuples.

So:

```
(string * string) list -> (string -> string)
```

Indicates a function which takes a list of tuples of two strings, and returns a function which takes a string and returns a string.

It's a good idea to get familiar with this syntax as you'll be seeing *a lot* of it.

A very simple function that matches this type is shown below. Please note that the pattern-matching contained within is non-exhaustive.

```
let f : (string * string) list -> (string -> string) = 
  fun ((a,b)::_) -> fun x -> x ^ a ^ b
```

When trying this at the top-level, you will see the below type. Due to the way functions work in OCaml, it is equivalent to the type signature you asked about, despite the missing parentheses.

```
(string * string) list -> string -> string
```